# Azure SQL service in Germany

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure

Although Azure seems to have datacenters in Germany, I cannot select that region when creating a new SQL server on Azure Portal.

The Azure pricing page show prices for this region, so why it is not listed in the available options? Any restrictions?

Comment: thats strange,i am able to repro the same behaviour,you can see SQLDatabase available here though:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/regions/services/

Comment: There may be restrictions on subscriptions that can create resources in certain regions depending on the "home" of the subscription. E.g. a US based subscription may not automatically be enabled to create a SQL DB in one of the German regions. Contact support for subscription management help on this.

Comment: I have engaged azure support on this

Answer (score 2):

There are restrictions on some Azure regions, based on your Azure account.  A US based Azure account will typically not be able to use these regions for tax and legal reasons.

Full details on the German data-center GA is at this blog https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-azure-germany-now-available-via-first-of-its-kind-cloud-for-europe/

*Customers in the EU and EFTA can continue to use Microsoft cloud options as they do today, or, for those who want the option, they’re able to use the services from German datacenters*

Comment: I have an application for a customer that will be deployed to a VPS hosted in Germany. Are you saying I cannot host my SQL database in Germany for this customer because of my Azure subscription restrictions? That will be hard to explain...

Comment: Please work with Azure support if you're blocked here.  More details here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/clouds/germany/#why-choose-azure-germany

Answer (score 2):

Since 2016 unfortunately nothing has changed until now (2023). Region **Germany West Central** (Frankfurt/Main) is available for **Azure SQL** but you can't create it. I worked last year a few month to install our infrastructure at Azure in that region until trying to create Azure SQL. You will get an error message when selecting the server location: "*This location is not available*" or "*Your subscription does not have access to create a server in the selected region.*"

[image]

This has nothing to do with free or pay-as-you-go subscription. The answer from the dev support after opening a ticket (october 2022):

> "Unfortunately, due to high demand for Azure SQL in this region, we
> are not able to approve your quota request at this time. To ensure
> that all customers can access the services they need, we are working
> through approving quota requests as we bring additional capacity
> online. We are continually investing in additional infrastructure to
> expand our available resources. Apologies for the delay in being able
> to increase the quota on your Azure subscription. No additional
> details are needed from you at this time, your request will stay
> pending. Thank you for your patience until we report back."

The problem is that microsoft is not working transparent und you loose so much time and money. **They simply have no resources anymore.**

People are asking this but they don't get answers and their questions get locked:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/94278a11-c5ac-4239-b092-a256bb5c4488/why-germany-west-central-location-is-not-available-for-subscription?forum=ssdsgetstarted

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac0376cb-2a0e-4dc2-a52c-d986989e6801/unable-to-create-sql-database-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted#00a598f2-5fd4-4c7e-ab91-913fae5ba7cc

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/52606

I am wondering whether Azure SQL resources in this region will be available after some time or not?

**UPDATE May 2023**

A new answer from azure support: "We are currently on track to approve requests for regional access **in early Q3 CY23**"

Comment: The same error for me on April 2023: "Sorry, we are currently experiencing high demand in Germany West Central region for the zonal redundant (Availability Zones) accounts, and cannot fulfill your request".
In the portal I cannot select region GermanyWestCentral and when I download the arm template and deploy manually, I get the error above.
If the database must be in another location as "West Europe" then all other resources need to be there too and the web app gets much slower because the latency to Frankfurt increase a lot.

Comment: I cannot believe this.... :(